# Weird NPE on BatchingBatcher "JDBC driver did not return the expected number of row counts"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm running a spring/hibernate java app on tomcat and I'm seeing this funky error on update:
JDBC driver did not return the expected number of row counts

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:262)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:179)
```

I recently updated my mysql connector to version 5.1.15.
Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Do you mind to provide the code which triggers this? Please, post your entities and the code between openSession and session.close.

Comment: check, have you setup batch size?

Comment: My batch size is 50. After this started happening I dropped it to 0 which of course is bad for performance. I haven't seen it today. next time the error occurs Ill post the details @paretnon.

Comment: Looking at the source code for BatchingBatcher - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/BatchingBatcher.java.html I think that the implementation is poor. The message that you cite is warning, not an error. Having detected an error condition, the code then proceeds to attempt to validate known bad data.  That said, the problem could be either that one of your statements has a syntax error, or is trying to return a result set. Your best bet would be to find out what statements are being executed when the problem happens, and then execute them individually and see each they returns.

Answer (score 2):

I think I encountered this once and fixed it by implementing hashCode and Equals methods for the object type returned by the query.